# Blogger template shows single column when signed in

Tags: blogger, template

I am hosting my blog on blogger.com using a custom domain. I am using one of the standard templates (Watermark) with a few extra widgets. It looks perfectly on all major browsers. However, the moment I log in to my google account my blog shows up as a single column. Right column is appended below the left column. I have not noticed any other major change.

Good thing is this is only visible to me (hopefully). But it bothers me. Does anybody know what might cause this?

Comment: When you are logged into Google, do they add any extra toolbars or buttons as admin of the blog into the page. It sounds like it is a CSS problem with one of the columns or widgets to large to fit.

Comment: Yes they do add extra links all over to manage existing posts, comments, widgets etc.

Comment: If it looks ok in Chrome, FireFox, Safari, and IE while logged out I think it's ok. If you really want to fix it, you'll need to view the CSS and HTML in Chrome Developer Tool or FireBug while logged in begin deleting some of the links to manage the blog etc and see which is causing the sidebar to be pushed down. But if it's only visible to you while logged in as the admin I wouldn't worry if it looks fine otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

[Anagio](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/10527/anagio) says:

> If it looks ok in Chrome, FireFox, Safari, and IE while logged out I think it's ok. If you really want to fix it, you'll need to view the CSS and HTML in Chrome Developer Tool or FireBug while logged in begin deleting some of the links to manage the blog etc and see which is causing the sidebar to be pushed down. But if it's only visible to you while logged in as the admin I wouldn't worry if it looks fine otherwise.